# Limiting datediff by Hours and Days

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Long time lurker and now i have my first question:

I'm designing a SQL Report. One Task is to calculate the amount of minutes between two Times. They can be the same day or on different days. In the Database there are 4 Columns given

- The Start Date (as Datetime e.g. 24.10.2017 00:00:00)
- The Start Time (as Datetime e.g. 01.01.1899 11:25:00)
- The End Date (formated as above)
- The End Time (formated as above)

I'm calculating three Filds, all in Minutes

- Days between: `=DateDiff("n", Fields!StartDatum.Value,Fields!QualDatum.Value)`
- Minutes between: `=DateDiff("n",Fields!StartZeit.Value,Fields!QualZeit.Value)`
- Adding those up: `=Fields!QualiZeitTage.Value+Fields!QualiZeitMinuten.Value`

All of this is working great and produces the desired output.

My Problem is, that i don't need the full time between those events. I only want to count minutes that are between 7:00 am and 8:00 pm. Also, i want to exclude Saturdays and Sundays. How would i go about limiting the `datediff` function to my desired times?

Second Problem: The Endtime and Date are only written when the event actually is finished. If it's still ongoing those Fields are empty producing a negative number (-1060764480 for example). Since i'm only using those to produce Boolean output on surpassing a certain length, it's no problem. I would like to handle that more "cleanly" though. Any thoughts?